# Correct synchronization firestore collection in MobX

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, synchronization, mobx

I'm trying do sync data from firestore in MobX and I have a problem with onSnapshot method.

I'm using flow and generator to do this. But I'm not sure how to handle correct sub/unsub listner from onSnapshot

```js
export class MyStore {
  @observable myItems: Array<MyModel> = [];
  sub: any //??

  constructor(){
    this.sync();
  }

  sync = flow(function*(this: MyStore) {
    const dbRef = firestore().collection('items');
    try {
        yield this.sub = dbRef.onSnapshot((data: any)=>{ //??
          // do something with data
          // const items = ...
          this.setItems(items);
        })
    } catch(error) {
      // error handling
    }
  })

  @action setItems = (items: MyModel[]) => {
    this.myItems = items;
  };
}
```

And how to correct unsubscribe? 
And another problem - only first sync call can catch the errors. When I'm changing something in firestore it changes myItems, but it skip try catch scope (it is running onlny in callback in onSnapshot method). How 'try/catch' every change on firestore?

Comment: Please only include one question in a post.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `onSnapshot` you get back a handle to the subscription. When you call that handle as a function, it unsubscribes from further updates.

So in your case:

```
this.sub();
```